# What is the word for the panel on a piano that is in front of the keyboard?

Tags: piano, terminology

Not the part of the piano that typically has the brand name on it, but the piece of wood that is under the keyboard and is in full view of the pianist.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The keybed is the part of the piano under the keyboard that supports the keyboard and stops the downward movement of the keys.

The key slip is the panel of wood in front of the white keys and keybed.

[image: piano parts]